# Regular expression for license plate number in Iran with Persian letters and digits

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, combinations, persian

I need a regular expression matching Iranian cars' license plate number.
the combination consists of a **two digit number** followed by **a Persian letter** and then another **three digit number**
like in the picture below:

[image]

It's necessary to allow user to input English digits (1-9) because some browsers or operating systems don't support Persian digits, but the letter **MUST** be Persian and cuz it's always supported.

EDIT:
Anyway I'm using c# in ASP.net MVC

Comment: What language or tool are you using ? and just to make sure, isn't the Persian alphabet the same as the Arabic alphabet ?

Comment: I'm using C# in ASP.net MVC. and no, the Persian alphabet is not the same as the Arabic alphabet!

Comment: Is it the Herbew alphabet ?

Comment: No it's Persian !!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for :

```
"[۱-۹\\d]{2}[\u0600-\u06FF][۱-۹\\d]{3}"
```

Works flawlessly with MVC data annotations, which I'm currently using it for
`[RegularExpression("[۱-۹\\d]{2}[\u0600-\u06FF][۱-۹\\d]{3}", ErrorMessage = "It's wrong!")]`

Thank to [Sniffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439667/sniffer) who helped me find the correct answer. :)
Wish you all find this helpful

Comment: You don't need `[۱-۹\\d]{2}` to match Persian digits because `\\d` already matches all kinds of digits. On the other hand, in C# you can use verbatim strings so you don't have to double escape everything, like this: `@"[۱-۹\d]{2}[\u0600-\u06FF][۱-۹\d]{3}"`

Comment: And could you please give me some credit *(up vote)* for helping you out.

Answer (score 4):

You can match this from the left to the right using the following regex:

```
\d{2}[\u0600-\u06FF]\d{3}
```

- `\d{2}` matches two consecutive digits.
- `[\u0600-\u06FF]` matches a single letter.
- `\d{3}` matches three consecutive digits.

Comment: Thanks ! it helped me struggle less and find the MORE CORRECT answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want the patter for the full string.

```
/[0-9۰-۹]{2}[الف|ب-ی|D]{1,3}[0-9۰-۹]{3}ایران[0-9۰-۹]{2}/
```

- `[0-9۰-۹]{2}`: Matches the first two digits, allowing for both English as well as Persian digits (accepts inputs regardless of user keyboard language).
- `[الف|ب-ی|D]{1,3}`: Matches one to three Persian letters. It covers a range of Persian characters, including "الف," "ب," "ت," and more, as well as the Latin letter "D" for diplomatic cars. You can also add more letters to accept all types of plate numbers. Note: You should also limit the input length for this section of the string.
- `[0-9۰-۹]{3}`: Matches the following three digits.
- `ایران`: This part of the pattern matches the literal word "ایران."
- `[0-9۰-۹]{2}`: Matches the final two digits of the license plate.